# I'm having trouble with input and output from files

Tags: python, math, python-3.4

I'm having some trouble with my code in python. I just started learning input and output in class, and how to have python read in data from text files(barely. I'm still a huge beginner). Anyways, my assignment is that I have to have my program read in data from a file and run it through my program. Problem is, I don't have a good idea on how to do that and was wondering if you guys could help me out. The text file just contains a huge life of numbers for python to use in my program. My program finds the mean, median, and standard deviation of a list of numbers that are given to it. Now, instead of user input data, my professor wants python to use data from a file that was already pre-written.

My code:

```
    import math

def mean(values):
    average = sum(values)*1.0/len(values)
    return average

def deviation(values):
    length = len(values)
    m = mean(values)
    total_sum = 0

    for i in range(length):
        total_sum += (values[i]-m)**2

    root = total_sum*1.0/length
    return math.sqrt(root)

def median(values):
    if len(values)%2 != 0:
        return sorted(values)[len(values)//2]
    else:
        midavg = (sorted(values)[len(values)//2] + sorted(values)[len(values)//2-1])//2.0
        return midavg

def main():
    x = [15, 17, 40, 16, 9]
    print (mean(x))
    print (deviation(x))
    print (median(x))

main()
```

Now, I have to edit my code so it opens the file, takes the data, and reads the data through my equations. Only problem is, I don't have a good idea on how to do that. Could anyone please help?

I've tried basic input and output myself, but it's done no justice in helping me with the bigger picture.

```
def main():
 total=0   
    input = open('Stats.txt')
    for nextline in input:
        mylist = nextline.split()
        for n in mylist:
           total+=int(n)
 print(total)
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample input? (i.e. the first few lines of the file)

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far to read from the file. Have you even tried looking up how to open and read files in the Python docs, or anywhere in Google?

Comment: Here you go. I took some of the data he wrote down in the .txt file for our program to use.  100
     30
     34
      9
     42
     98
     17
     89
     57
      8
     83
     24
     60
     92
     65
     18
     85
     56
     38
     79
     31
    100
     53
I know how to open files. file = open("newfile.txt", "r"). Simple stuff, but, I don't have an understanding yet on writing the code in my current program to read data from the .txt file and run it through my equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fill your list from the file.

Open the file and iterate over the lines. Convert the content of the line to an `integer` and append it to your list. If you don't cxonvert the data you'll get strings and those won't work with mathematical operations. Close your file.

Now work with your list.

```
filename = 'newfile.txt'
data = []
source = open(filename)
for line in source:
    data.append(int(line))
source.close()

print(mean(data))
print(deviation(data))
# more stuff with data
```

There is a way to let Python close the file for you so you won't have to remember it.

```
with open(filename) as source:
    for line in source:
        data.append(int(line))
```

According to your edit this might not be what you want. If the numbers are in one line, rather than one number per line, you'll have to take a different approach (`split`).

Comment: Yes, there are in one long vertical line. Now, I edited my code some and it's telling me that Stats isn't define in the line source = open(Stats). I just can't seem to grasp this input of data idea at all. Alright, so. I added the code in and now my program is working correctly, but it's taking the whole list and finding the mean, median, and standard deviation from the whole list, instead of grabbing snippets of numbers to use.